# What to add to my regex?

Tags: php, regex

I work with a regex, but I have a little problem :

```
preg_match_all('/<b>([0-9]*%)[ ]?positif<\/b>/Us', $pourcentage, $notation);
```

When the string is this, it works :

```
<b>89% positif </b>au cours des derniers 12 mois. (101 évaluations totales)
```

And when it is this, it doesn't work :

```
 <b>90% positif. </b>(39 évaluations totales)
```

So I know that the problem is the `.` at the end of "positif", so how to add in my regex a rule that say "with the `.` or without ?

Thanks.
(Sorry for my english)

Comment: but your first string won't contain any b tag.

Comment: "So I know that the problem is the . at the end" No the problem is you are trying to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Avinash Raj : I edited, sorry
@PeeHaa : It's possible, and now it works ;-)
downvoters : Why did you downvote my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so how to add in my regex a rule that say "with the . or without ?

Just make the dot as optional one by adding `?` quantifier next to that dot. It would be like, `\.?`

```
<b>([0-9]*%)[ ]?positif\.? *<\/b>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jG2wO4/14)

Answer (score 2):

```
<b>([0-9]*%)[ ]?positif.*<\/b>
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jG2wO4/13

Comment: `.` means "any character". Try escaping `\.` instead.

Comment: Right, but he might not want to have anything else. His turn to give more details then. :)

Comment: @caCtus Op 's example `<b>90% positif. </b>` after positif there is a `.space`